# What is the difference between these two types of code? I can't tell even though they output different values

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, directive

I was working a problem on a site (https://www.learn-c.org/en/While_loops) focused on teaching the basics in C. When I was supposed to solve this problem I thought it was easy and I had an answer immediately in mind. However, it turns out it was wrong.

This was my approach. It gave this output: 7 5 9 5 6

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int array[] = {1, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 5, 11, 6, 3, 4};
int i = 0;

while (i < 10) {
    i++;
    if(array[i]<5||array[i]>10)
        continue;

    printf("%d\n", array[i]);

}

return 0;
}
```

And this was the solution. which gave this output: 7 5 9 5

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int array[] = {1, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 5, 11, 6, 3, 4};
int i = 0;

while (i < 10) {
    if(array[i] < 5){
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    if(array[i] > 10){
        break;
    }

    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

I have looked everywhere I could think of to find an answer but I just can't seem to understand what the difference between my solution and the solution provided is.

Provided solution output: `7 5 9 5`

My solution output: `7 5 9 5 6`

Comment: One solution has a `break;` in it? Are you unclear on the difference between `break` and `continue`?

Comment: Omorio, Why use 10 in `while (i < 10)`?  What is special about 10 here?

Comment: @chux Seems like it is just the hardcoded array size I think.

Comment: It might be a small mistake and it can be removed from account as the last element will not be considered in any case

Comment: @Osiris Even thought the linked ref says "The array variable consists of a sequence of ten numbers".   `int array[] = {1, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 5, 11, 6, 3, 4};`  has 11 elements.

Comment: @chux I also noticed that. But at least in example one he increments `i` at the beginning of the loop, so it has to be `< 10` when entering. It does not make sense though.

Comment: Omorio, "What is the difference between theses two types of code?"  --> At least one difference: First code continues after encountering  `array[i]>10` and the second code breaks out of the loop on the same condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First difference: after entering you increase `i` by one: line 8 (`i++`).
So you start with the 2nd value in the array; that makes no difference in output but it is quite a difference.

Second the `break` does exactly what the exercise asked: if the value is greater than ten you should not print it **and** stop the loop. The break exits the loop surrounding it and thereby fulfills the requirement. The break exits the outer loop and continues with the next line after the loop (return 0) so even if the condition in the while loop would be (i<1000) the output for the code with the break would be the same.
In the provided case the while loop runs 8 times, because the 11 is at index 8 in the loop, but in general the break has nothing to do with the number of times the loop is executed, it only depends on the condition which needs to be true (if statement) to execute it.

And third: you are asked to use two if statements while you are only using one which checks for two conditions.

And fourth you changed the code which was provided, the code included a `i++` after the `printf` which is not there in your code.

Comment: Ah okay, many thanks. So to ask a question to check if I understand it now. The break basically makes the code jump to the beginning of the loop incrementing the     i value by one and then also checks if the loop has run 10 times? Also does the break make it run <=10 times or <10 times?

Comment: No the break just exits the outer loop. So it jumps to the next line after the while loop, which is the return 0 statement

Comment: I updated my answer this hopefully answers your question

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the `break` statement.

In your code the loop keeps executing until the `i < 10` condition is met (effectively iterating through the numbers 1, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 5, 11, 6, 3 and skipping the last one).
In this code, the numbers between 5 and 9 of the previously mentioned numbers will get printed.

In the answers code, the loop **STOPS** when the break condition is met, ie, when the number 11 is reached. If it were to continue, then the answers would be the same.